# On the equation involving Stirling numbers of the second kind ${n\brace a}{m\brace b}={k\brace c}$, and its solutions satisfying certain requirements

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, divisors-multiples, stirling-numbers

In this post we denote the Stirling numbers of the second kind as ${r\brace s}$ and we consider the proposal to ask if the equation of the title has infinitely many solutions $${n\brace a}{m\brace b}={k\brace c}\tag{1}$$
with the additional requirements $2\leq a$, $2\leq b$ and $2\leq c$, and $a+1<n$, $b+1<m$ and $c+1<k$ for the integers $m,n,k,a,b$ and $c$ in our equation.

The Stirling numbers of the second kind have a good mathematical content in combinatorics.

The additional requirements are due to make a more interesting question.

**Example.** A solution is $(n,a;m,b;k;c)=(7,2;6,4;13,2)$ since

$${7\brace 2}\cdot{6\brace 4}=63\cdot65=4095={13\brace 2}.$$ A table for some of first few solutions is given below.

> **Question.** Has the equation $${n\brace a}{m\brace b}={k\brace c}$$
>   infinitely many solutions $(n,a;m,b;k;c)$ for positive integers $m,n,k,a,b$ and $c$ satisfying the conditions $2\leq a$, $2\leq b$, $2\leq c$, $a+1<n$, $b+1<m$ and $c+1<k$? **Many thanks.**

With a Pari/GP, this **line** of code that you can to run in the web Sage Cell Server, choose *GP* as Language and press Evaluate,

`for(n=2, 20, for(m=2, 20, for(k=2,20, for(a=2,20, for(b=2, 20, for(c=2, 20, if((a+1<n)&&(b+1<m)&&(c+1<k)&&stirling(n,a,{flag=2})*stirling(m,b,{flag=2})==stirling(k,c,{flag=2}),print(n))))))))`

one can to get examples of solutions denoted as $(n,m,k;a,b,c)$. The implementarion of the Stirling number of the second kind is from an user's guide to Pari/GP of the Université de Bordeaux.

The table of solutions that I've calculated and that thus I know is the following:

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
n&a&m&b&k&c \\
\hline
5&3&18&4&10&5\\
\hline
5&3&18&16&17&14 \\
\hline
6&4&7&2&13&2\\
\hline
 7&2&6&4&13&2\\
\hline
 8&4&5&3&10&5\\
\hline
18&16&5&3&17&14 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: All, feel free to add comments about the mathematical content of my Question, and in particular add or remove more suitable tags.